# how to dynamically adding the fields

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add field dynamically 
there is two field
1. Input text
2. time 
but they are not working while trying to add them dynamically.
here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxField = 5; //Input fields increment limitation
  var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
  var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
  var fieldHTML = '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-5"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1">EVENTS</label><input type="text" id="firstdayevent" name="firstdayevent[]" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email"></div></div><div class="col-sm-5"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1">EVENT\'S TIME </label><div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker"><input id="timepicker1" name="firsdayeventtime[]" type="text" class="form-control input-small"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span></div></div></div>'; //New input field html 
  var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1

  //Once add button is clicked
  $(addButton).click(function() {
    //Check maximum number of input fields
    if (x < maxField) {
      x++; //Increment field counter
      $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); //Add field html
    }
  });

  //Once remove button is clicked
  $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
    x--; //Decrement field counter
  });
});


$('#timepicker1').timepicker({
  showInputs: false
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.timepicker/0.2.6/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.timepicker/0.2.6/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
<div class="field_wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">EVENTS</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstdayevent" name="firstdayevent[]" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">EVENT'S TIME</label>
        <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
          <input id="timepicker1" name="firsdayeventtime[]" type="text" class="form-control input-small">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

I'm just trying to add dynamically they both field.
one is text & second is the time picker.
they cannot dynamically adding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an un-escaped single quote inside your single quoted statement for `var fieldHTML`. You also have multiple spaces inside that same line of codes `<div>` and `<span>` tags. --> `</i > < /span></div > < /div></div >` at the end of that line. Also I see no remove button in your code.

```
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">EVENT'S TIME</label>
```

Should be escaped with backward slash:

```
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">EVENT\'S TIME</label>
```

***SIDE NOTE :***  Also, FYI the FONT AWESOME link is not included in your snipit, I had to add text there to see the submit button and trouble shoot the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxField = 5; //Input fields increment limitation
  var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
  var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
  var fieldHTML = '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-5"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1">EVENTS</label><input type="text" id="firstdayevent" name="firstdayevent[]" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email"></div></div><div class="col-sm-5"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1">EVENT\'S TIME</label><div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker"><input id="timepicker1" name="firstdayeventtime[]" type="text" class="timepicker1 form-control input-small"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span></div></div></div><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove Field">Remove Me</i></a></div>'; //New input field html 
  var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1

  //Once add button is clicked
  $(addButton).click(function() {
    //Check maximum number of input fields
    if (x < maxField) {
      x++; //Increment field counter
      $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); //Add field html
    }
  });

  //Once remove button is clicked
  $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').empty(); //Remove field html
    x--; //Decrement field counter
  });
});

$('.timepicker1').each(function(e){
    $(this).timepicker({
      showInputs: false
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.timepicker/0.2.6/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.timepicker/0.2.6/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
<div class="field_wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">EVENTS</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstdayevent" name="firstdayevent[]" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">EVENT'S TIME</label>
        <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
          <input id="timepicker1" name="firstdayeventtime[]" type="text" class="timepicker1 form-control input-small">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">FA NOT INCLUDED</i></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you make it those field should remove also

Comment: each field should contain a remove button.

Comment: please check second time date does not appearing

Comment: open in full page or scroll down the snipit iframe

Comment: yes i did. but still there is a problem time picker does not working one dynamically added field. please look over them

Comment: Remove button working now. Now 100% sure why the timepicker is not working, I would try wrapping the callback in an each loop and try calling on this. Id also change the selectors to classes as well.